# Getting URL of uploaded image to a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a CPT called books and I am able to loop through it like this but I need to get the URL of the uploaded images into the post (not in Gallery). I tried to use WP `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` as below but I do not know what should I pass for `$attachment_id` as it is required

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'romance'
        )
    )
)
);
while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();
  $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src('', 'full' );
   if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Apparently this is not returning any of images uploaded to the CPT URL. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you use ACF ?

Comment: @BrijeshDhanani - You can't pass the post id to the function, it is the image ID that is needed.

Comment: **Please try following code and let me know if you have any concern** `$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$img_id = get_term_meta($page_object->term_id, 'your meta', true);
$img_url_full = wp_get_attachment_url($img_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace with Your Functon.

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'romance'
        )
    )
)
);
while ($loop->have_posts()):
  $loop->the_post();
  //used "get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID)" perameter
  $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID), 'full' );
   if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

?>
```